# Mule Exception strategy definition: Invalid content was found starting with element 'choice-exception-strategy'

Tags: mule

I'm developing a mule work-flow to insert a record into the database, trying to catch the exception in case if the record is already present and send the HTTP status (409-Conflict) and the back to the client.

```
<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method'] == 'POST']"> 
                        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
                        <set-variable variableName="id" value="#[message.payload.id]" doc:name="Save brandId"/>
                        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
                        <db:insert config-ref="Postgres" doc:name="Configstore">
                            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO messages("id", "data") VALUES ( #[flowVars['id']], CAST(#[message.payload] as json))]]> </db:parameterized-query>
                        </db:insert>
                        <logger message="REST Response = #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="LOG Rest Response"></logger>

                         <choice-exception-strategy name="Global_Choice_Exception_Strategy" doc:name="Global Choice Exception Strategy">
                            <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch_Exception_Strategy" when="#[exception.causedBy(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException)]">
                            <set-payload value="The request cannot be processed, the error is #[exception.getExceptionPayload()]"/>
                                <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="404"/> 
                                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                            </catch-exception-strategy>
                         </choice-exception-strategy>  

                    </when>
```

The start-up is repeatedly failing and the following error reported in the logs.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'choice-exception-strategy'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

This error alternatively reported for both choice-exception-strategy and catch-exception-strategy. Not sure what's invalid here or need to define a custom message-processor or outbound-endpoint. I'm using mule EE-3.8.0

Comment: It should be in flow level. Define it before end of the `</flow>` like. <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Global_Choice_Exception_Strategy"> <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException)]" doc:name="Catch_Exception_Strategy">
                <set-payload value="The request cannot be processed, the error is #[exception.getExceptionPayload()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    .....
            </catch-exception-strategy>
        </choice-exception-strategy>
        </flow>. If you are using Intellji GUI will be missing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an exception strategy within a choice element. The exception strategy must be defined for your whole flow, not single elements (some do allow them though but are rare cases). You can find more on this [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/error-handling) and an example [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/tests/integration/src/test/resources/org/mule/test/integration/exceptions/choice-exception-strategy.xml).

HTH